# Try Except inside an elif, not working as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this part of code, Even though the condition is met in case of `if obj.overtime_approve == False:`. following lines are not exceuted after that condition. I couldn't understand the reason.

Here `obj` is coming from a method and it can be `dict` or `object`. Hence I added a `try` block.
Is anything wrong in my code?

```
elif given_date.weekday() == 4:
            try:
                if obj.overtime_approve == False:
                    print("yep")
                    friday_ot_hours = 0
                    holiday_ot_hours = 0
                    normal_hours = 0
                    normal_ot_hours = 0
                    total_hours = normal_ot_hours + normal_hours
            except Exception as e:
                if obj['overtime_approve'] == False:
                    print("yes")
                    friday_ot_hours = 0
                    holiday_ot_hours = 0
                    normal_hours = 0
                    normal_ot_hours = 0
                    total_hours = normal_ot_hours + normal_hours
```

edit:

Initially the code was like this.

```
elif given_date.weekday() == 4 and obj.overtime_approve == False:
            friday_ot_hours = 0
            holiday_ot_hours = 0
            normal_hours = 0
            normal_ot_hours = 0
            total_hours = normal_ot_hours + normal_hours
```

But the `obj` can be a type of `<class 'dict'>` or `<class 'apps.employee.models.UpdatedPunchRawDataProcesses'>`.

Hence I added try except block in order to solve this problem. Is there any efficient method to do this?

Comment: why are you wrapping all of that in a `try/except` statement? there are things in there that can not go wrong (such as `friday_ot_hours = 0`). what is the actual exception (in which line of this code) that you want to catch?

Comment: the only thing i see there that could raise an exception is `obj.overtime_approve` - namely if `obj` does not have a `overtime_approve` member. why not just catch that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead to test what kind of object you're working with.

```py
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    over_time = obj['overtime_approve']
elif isinstance(obj, UpdatedPunchRawDataProcesses):  # Replace this with whatever your class actually is
    over_time = obj.overtime_approve
else:
    raise TypeError("obj should only be dict or apps.employee.models.UpdatedPunchRawDataProcesses")

if over_time == False:
    friday_ot_hours = 0
    holiday_ot_hours = 0
    normal_hours = 0
    normal_ot_hours = 0
    total_hours = normal_ot_hours + normal_hours
```

Comment: *Generally we try to avoid raising exceptions where possible.* the [python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) does not agree with that (in general). but in this case i think you are right. +1

Comment: You are correct. Thank you, old habits die hard it seems on the LYBL approach. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just rewrite this as follows:

```py
elif given_date.weekday() == 4:
    try:
        overtime_approve = (
            obj['overtime_approve']
            if isinstance(obj, dict)
            else obj.overtime_approve
        ) # You can write this on one line without the parentheses, if you want.
    except:
        ... # obj is of an unsupported type! Handle this error.

    if not overtime_approve:
        ... # Set all your stuff
```

[EDIT: I like Henry Ecker's solution for checking the type of `obj` more, but neither of our answers covers the case where `obj` is a `dict` but doesn't have the `overtime_approve` key. You may want to do a separate `try except` specifically for that case, if there's a chance `obj` as a `dict` won't have that key, and depending on the granularity of error reporting you want.]

This way you're: a.) not repeating code, and b.) capturing just the potential error point in a `try` block.

Just a nitpick: there's no need to compare boolean values against `True` and `False`. Using `if my_boolean_value:` and `if not my_boolean_value:` is cleaner and more readable.